# regex for interval of years

Tags: c#, regex, enterprise-library

In C#, I want to write a regular expression that will accept only years between 1900 and 2099.

I tried `^([1][9]\d\d|[2][0]\d\d)$`, but this does not work.  Any ideas?

So i have in a class:

```
    [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "Anul nu poate sa lipseasca!")]
  //  [RangeValidator(1900, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 2100, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, MessageTemplate = "Anul trebuie sa contina 4 caractere!")]
    [RegexValidator(@"(19|20)\d{2}$", MessageTemplate = "Anul trebuie sa fie valid!", Ruleset = "validare_an")]
    public int anStart
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And in a test method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void anStartTest()
{
    AnUnivBO target = new AnUnivBO() { anStart = 2009 };
    ValidationResults vr = Validation.Validate<AnUnivBO>(target, "validare_an");
    Assert.IsTrue(vr.IsValid);
}
```

Why it fails?

Comment: Your pattern is valid as is, although it could be shortened. Please post some sample code showing how you're using it to demonstrate why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a string property, not an integer, for the RegexValidator to work:

```
public string anStart
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

In your test method you would need to use:

```
AnUnivBO target = new AnUnivBO() { anStart = "2009" };
```

To continue using an integer use a [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309347.aspx):

```
[RangeValidator(1900, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,
                2099, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive)]
public anStartint anStart 
{
   get; set;
)
```

Comment: And if i wanna use anStart as an integer, and validate it being between 1900 and 2099 what should i use? RangeValidator?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^(19|20)\d{2}$
```

Comment: Also a valid answer. `{2}` means: look for two of these.

Answer (score 2):

You should leave out the `[]`, for those are indicators for character classes

`/^(19\d\d|20\d\d)$/`

also, regexes are slow. using `if(date <= 2099 && date>=1900)` is much faster

Comment: -(-1).  Now, about that "regexes are slow" comment...  :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

^((19\d\d)|(20\d\d))$

Comment: @TGOD: If this were a copy of your answer, it would contain the sequence `/d`, which matches a forward-slash followed by the letter 'd'.  But as you can see, this answer contains `\d`, the escape sequence for a digit.  Which, now I think about, will probably work a little better, don't you think? :@

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `^(19|20)\d\d$` works.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat=re.compile("^(19|20)\\d\\d$")
>>> print re.match(pat,'1999')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7c714a0>
>>> print re.match(pat,'2099')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7c714a0>
>>> print re.match(pat,'1899')
None
>>> print re.match(pat,'2199')
None
>>> print re.match(pat,'21AA')
None
```